# How can I tell if my Apache2+PHP uses CGI/FCGI?

Tags: php, apache2

If I haven't setup FastCGI or mod_php, does that mean my vanilla Apache2 uses CGI for PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`php_sapi_name()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php) to find out.

Comment: returns `apache2handler`. in my mods enabled I see php5.conf - so does this mean it uses mod_php and not cgi?

Answer (score 6):

`phpinfo()` includes this information on it's third row of output as 'Server API'.

In your case (running under mod_php), 'Apache 2.0 Handler' will be displayed.

For one reason or another, `php_sapi_name()` didn't work for me.